# Binding a label's text to an index in a list XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

So in the code behind I am pulling from a sqlite database and creating a list of people with various properties. I want to attach the Name property to the text of a button. Here is the object in the code behind (I have it in the OnAppearing method):

```
List<Person> People = await App.PersonRep.GetAllPeople();
```

I am trying to bind a specific index from this list to the button in XAML but am struggling to find a solution that works. Is putting the button within a listview the only way? I was hoping to do something that may look cleaner or be more simple

EDIT more code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView x:Name="peopleList">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell Height="30">
                    <StackLayout Padding="5">
                        <Button Text="{Binding People[0].PersonName}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And then this in the code behind:

```
public List<Person> People { get; set; }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        PopulatePeople();

    }



    public async void PopulatePeople()
    {
        List<Person> People = await App.PeopleRepo.GetAllPeople();
            peopleList.ItemsSource = People;
```

And then this is the GetAllPeople method from the PeopleRepository class (a PeopleRepo object of type PeopleRepository is also created in the App class):

```
        public SQLiteAsyncConnection conn;
    public PeopleRepository(string db)
    {
        conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(db);
        conn.CreateTableAsync<Person>().Wait();
    }

        public async Task<List<Person>> GetAllPeople()
    {
        try
        {
             return await conn.Table<Person>().ToListAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Status = string.Format("Failed to retrieve data. {0}", ex.Message);
        }

        return new List<Person>();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [] in Binding paths to refer to an index

in your code

```
//you can only bind to public properties
public List<Person> People { get; set; }
```

in your XAML

```
<Label Text="{Binding People[10].Name}" />
```

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work. I am pulling from a SQLite database async. When I try displaying the entire list of a property in a listview it works, but not when I try to specify a specific item. How would you incorporate the get; set; into the code that I mentioned to pull from the database async?

Comment: Is there just a single button, or does every item in the list have a button?

Comment: Yes the name property for every item will have a button and every item will have multiple other properties. Each property will be used to populate either a entry/picker/button/datepicker and those things will also be used to set them and save them to the database.

Comment: Then that is just a ListView.  I really don't understand what you're trying to do that is causing a problem for you.  Can you please update your original question with the code that you are unable to get to work and a better explanation of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I updated the code above. Right now I have a SQLite database with a Person table. This person has several people with things like PersonId, PersonName among other things. Here I am trying to pull an instance of Person (the first instance in this case) and set the text of the button as the PersonName from that instance

Comment: I'll also add that if I change <Button Text="{Binding People[0].PersonName}" /> to <Button Text="{Binding PersonName}" /> it will display all of the PersonNames. It just won't accept my displaying one specific one for some reason

Comment: if your query returns 10 People, then your List will have 10 rows, and each row will display the name of one person.  Do you want to display a different person's name?

Comment: It is to show one person's name within this button. The app will have functionality where if a user clicks that button it will show labels and datepickers that are pulled from other properties in that instance of that person. I think I have a solution though it may not be the cleanest way to go. In the PopulatePeople() method I put this:             List<Person> People = await App.TermRep.GetAllPeople();
            var per1 = People[0];
            List<Person> per = new List<Person>
            {
                per1
            };
            peopleList.ItemsSource = per;

Comment: if you only want to show the info for one person then you shouldn't be using a ListView

Comment: Yeah that was my original poorly worded and poorly setup question, what a good alternative to a listview would be

Comment: To just display a page of data?  A grid with Labels (or Entry if you need to edit them).  You would set the BindingContext of the page to your Person, then bind the Labels (or Entry) to the various properties of Person you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can go about this.

One way could be creating a combobox and assigning the list as `ItemsSource`. Then you make could make some labels and input and assign the selected person in the combobox as `DataContext` for the window.

Say for example that this is the XAML:

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="personCombobox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionChanged="personCombobox_OnSelectionChanged">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" - " />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
        <Label Content="{Binding FirstName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding LastName, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

And then the code behind would look something like this:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            personCombobox.ItemsSource = personRepository.GetAll();
            personCombobox.SelectedIndex = 0;

        }

 private void personCombobox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (personCombobox.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                this.DataContext = (Person)personCombobox.Items.GetItemAt(personCombobox.SelectedIndex);
            }
        }
```